# Bidirectional OneToMany and ManyToOne returns "NULL not allowed for column" on save

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, jpa-2.0

This is a shortened version of the entities where I only show the relevant parts.

```
    @Entity
    @Data
    public class Wrapper {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "wrapper", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
        private Application application;

        public Wrapper(Application application) {
            this.application = application;
            application.setWrapper(this);
        }
    }

    @Data
    @Entity
    @EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "wrapper")
    public class Application {
        @Id
        private Integer id;

        @JsonIgnore
        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "id")
        @MapsId
        private Wrapper wrapper;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "application", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @SortNatural
        private SortedSet<Apartement> ownedApartements = new TreeSet<>();
    }

    @Entity
    @Data
    public class Apartement {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "application_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private Application application;
    }

@Repository
public interface WrapperRepository extends JpaRepository<Wrapper, Integer> {
}
```

The above entities generates the following create table statements:

```
create table Wrapper (
       id int identity not null,
        primary key (id)
    )

create table Application (
       id int not null,
        primary key (id)
    )

    create table Apartement (
       id int identity not null,
        application_id int not null,
        primary key (id)
    )

     alter table Apartement 
       add constraint FKsrweh1i1p29mdjfp03or318od 
       foreign key (application_id) 
       references Application

       alter table Application
       add constraint FKgn7j3pircupa2rbqn8yte6kyc 
       foreign key (id) 
       references Wrapper
```

Given the follow entities and the following code:

```
Apartement apartement1 = new Apartement()
Apartement apartement2 = new Apartement()

Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(new Application());

Application application = wrapper.getApplication();
application.getOwnedApartements().addAll(Arrays.asList(apartement1, apartement2));
apartement1.setApplication(application);
apartement2.setApplication(application);

WrapperRepository.saveAndFlush(wrapper);
```

I see three inserts in the log.
First wrapper, then application, and finally apartement. But for some reason application_id is null on the first save. But I know it has a bi-directional relationship.

The error I get is:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "APPLICATION_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into Apartement (id) values (null) [23502-197]
```

Why does this happen? Do I need to store everything in the correct order? Do I need to first store wrapper and application, then finally store the apartement once I have application ID?
Cannot hibernate store all three in one go? Or figure this out it self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I fixed it.

The problem was

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "application_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private Application application;
```

I removed insertable = false, updatable = false and added optional=false

That worked

```
@JoinColumn(name = "application_id", optional = false)
```

Comment: I don't think you meant `= false` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Apartement apartement1 = new Apartement()
Apartement apartement2 = new Apartement()

Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(new Application());

Application application = wrapper.getApplication();
application.getOwnedApartements().addAll(Arrays.asList(apartement1, apartement2));
apartement1.setApplicationId(application.getId());
apartement2.setApplicationId(application.getId());

WrapperRepository.saveAndFlush(wrapper);
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I have. Whats the difference exactly